# jquery smoothscroll not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I have a JQuery event listener that is supposed to prevent the default 'jump to div' function on hyperlinks with the `.smoothscroll` class and instead animate the scroll of the document to the div.

It works fine on Safari but for some reason it doesn't do anything on Chrome. It prevents the document from jumping directly to the element but it doesn't do anything other than that. I've checked that the function calls when the hyperlink is clicked but I'm at loss why it doesn't animate.

My hyperlink:

```
<a class="smoothscroll" href="#slide2">GO</a>
```

My JQuery function:

```
$(function(){
    $('.smoothscroll').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log($(id).offset().top);
        console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

If this is any help, `$(id).offset().top` does actually return the right value in px to scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i tried your code on my Chrome browser and it is working pretty well. You just need to put `id="slide2"` to the div you want to scroll to and it's done. Try to remove the cache of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

can you use this here?

jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").on("click", function(event) {

// Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
if (this.hash !== "") {
  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // Using jQuerys animate() method to add smooth page scroll
  // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 1600, function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
  });
}
});
});
```